# SQL выборка по дате

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Пишу запрос на выборку ТОП-10 покупателей. Вывести покупателей за все время я смог запросто, но встал вопрос о сортировке по дате. 
Записал запрос таким образом, все выполняется, но сортировки по UNIX столбцу o.date не происходит. 
Запрос:

```
SELECT o.user_id, SUM(o.total_price) as nsum, o.date as odate, u.id as uid, u.balance as balance, u.name as login
FROM s_orders as o,s_users as u    
WHERE user_id!='NULL'  
AND   o.user_id=u.id  
AND   o.date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY))   
GROUP BY user_id  
ORDER BY nsum DESC   
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: а где в этом запросе сортировка по столбцу `o.date`? может имелось в виду, что условие `WHERE` не выполняется?

Answer (score 1):

1. чтобы была сортировка по столбцу o.date её нужно явно указать в части ORDER BY
2. сейчас o.date выбирается случайным образом из группы с одинаковым user_id, так как указан без групповых функций

Предположу, что вы хотите получить дату последнего заказа для каждого юзера, тогда используйте max(o.date) as odate

Comment: Можете показать в коде, что имеете в виду? Не получается результат, внеся ваши правки.

Comment: сделайте пример тестовых данных на sqlfiddle.com и какой должен быть на них результат. пока вы не уточнили, что имеете в виду по сортировкой, слоно понять что именно вам нужно